# Twitter API 1.1: Streaming API and OAuth

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

In the light of announced Twitter API 1.1 ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api)): currently Streaming API supports both OAuth and Basic authentication ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)); will this remain, or applications that use Basic authentication will need to use OAuth as well? Asking this because not aware that announced changes will affect Streaming API.

Comment: The best thing to do here is asking it to @twitterapi.

Comment: Asked the question in parallel at dev.twitter.com and received the answer: [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10262). Shortly: yes, Basic Auth will be supported as well

Answer (score 0):

I see, [in the same place](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10262), that the basic auth won't be accepted forever by the streaming API (the only that supports it now). So it's a matter of time about when they'll switch it off completely.